Grub launches and installation doesn't start, Ubuntu 24.04
I've tried to install Ubuntu 24.04 to Lenovo IdeaPad Slim 5. Downloaded the ISO and created a bootable USB Stick.
In BIOS in the EFI, this USB stick shows as a possible option to load. But when I start loading from the USB it displays me a Grub screen. I'm trying to start booting from USB but nothing works.
I tried the ls command and set (memstick) as a root to boot from USB. But when I type "boot" after that it says that it needs kernel to be loaded at first.
Can anyone help me to handle this problem?

It's helpful if you're specific with details; is this a Ubuntu Core 24 you are trying to boot?  (You mention Ubuntu 24 which isn't actually a Ubuntu product/release; Ubuntu Core 24 the closest). Did you verify ISO?  and how did you write ISO to media? as if reformatted (via options in ISO writing software) you must use options suitable for your hardware (or just clone it without change for best results)

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. I used Drofus to burn ISO from Android. Because here I don't have any other computers. And I format USB Stick.

You don't format a USB stick, as writing correctly will overwrite any formatting of USB stick as the formatting options are encoded on the ISO itself... Given you mention formatting, you must ensure your drofus tool was equipped for 24.04 ISOs (was it?) and you used correct options for your media (as you're not using Ubuntu defaults; but options you specified)...  Your error implies you didn't use a valid writing tool OR incorrect options for your hardware.. I suggest using a simple clone method if ISO write so the defaults get used (defaults coming from ISO itself)

This question is similar to: Can we use EtchDroid to create Ubuntu installation media?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The solution is similar to this one - https://askubuntu.com/a/1524737/1915224
The problem was that Ubuntu 24.04 doesn't support 13th-generation Intel Core i7. I used this page to check: https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/intel-iot And when I selected the 13th gen intel it showed that I can install Ubuntu 22.04. Then I downloaded it, created a bootable USB Stick via balenaEtcher, and installed it without any problems. Probably it may help someone.
Thanks to anyone for your help.
